# Splitting protocol buffer definitions into multiple .proto files

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I would like to include a protocol definition file in another protocol file. For example:

```
// base.proto:
message P_EndPoint {
  required int32 id = 1;
  required string host = 2;
  required int32 port = 3;
}
```

Then in another file:

```
communication.proto:
// somehow include `base.proto'
// ...
message P_CommunicationProtocol {
  required CP_MessageType type = 1;
  optional int32 id = 2;
  optional P_EndPoint identity = 3;
  repeated P_EndPoint others = 4;
}
// ...
```

(Note: developers.google.com is not available in my locale)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#other specifically the part labeled "Importing Definitions"

Comment: I can't access that URL.

Comment: this makes me realize how old grpc is!!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
import "myproject/base.proto";
```

Docs: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#importing

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not doing my own search. Google Developers is not accessible in my country. [(I see this)](http://s2.picofile.com/file/7789729137/arch12.png)

Comment: Because of the stupid politics. US Export control laws restrict providing certain services to some countries. This really sucks. I'm a student. I'm not trying to make bombs! I just wanna finish my final project on CSP course :|

Comment: No worries. I edited your Q so I could remove my downvote. Glad I could help.

Comment: I'd suggest something like googling "anonymous http proxy" but that would probably violate some laws or something.

Comment: Oh dude :) You really don't know what are you talking about. Living here is really difficult. VPN, SOCKS, Certain IPs, Certain protocols, are blocked. Data transmission is sniffed at both ISP and governmental level. No way you can get real internet here :D

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't look at your profile until just now. Ignore that I said anything :) Ask any damn thing you want on here, and mention where you are.

Comment: I know the pain @sorush-r :) glad you made it out of that place man

Answer (score 1):

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "Protos/general.proto";
```

[image]